# Microsoft Graph call requesting Company Administrator

Tags: microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

In the context of automating A-AD invitations via a dedicated Azure hosted web application, one of our calls is making the call below to the Graph API (leveraging Microsoft.Graph & Microsoft.Graph.Core assemblies). 
The code is raising an exception if the Company Administrator role is not granted (which poses an issue with our security team). Any advice around this, thank you (tried User Administrator, Help Administrator, etc.)?

Apparently a recent change in Azure AD made this appear.

```
 _client.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
where _client is GraphServiceClient ( Microsoft.Graph Dll ) and user is MSGraph.User( Microsoft.Graph Dll )
var user = new User()
{
GivenName = pendingRegistration.GivenName,
Surname = pendingRegistration.SurName,
StreetAddress = pendingRegistration.Address,
PostalCode = pendingRegistration.PostalCode,
City = pendingRegistration.City,
State = pendingRegistration.State,
Country = pendingRegistration.Country,
MobilePhone = pendingRegistration.Mobile,
JobTitle = pendingRegistration.JobTitle
};
```